# Repeated measures analysis... or not?

Tags: repeated-measures, seasonality

Not sure if dealing with repeated measures analysis...? Measuring X at 3 seasons (summer, winter, spring/fall) during a year – might be high summer/low winter, high winter/low summer, consistently high, consistently low, etc. Y (health outcome) measured at same 3 times. Time between measures not fully equal between participants. Y may or may not change within the short time frame. Main question is whether seasonal variation in X is associated with Y. ie. would someone with consistent-X in all seasons have healthier Y vs. someone with more variability in X? Might just be multiple linear/logistic regression… or is it repeated measures, or ANCOVA…?  And then what if in some cases X appears to increase (or decrease) in a season but it's not due to season, ie. rather a permanent change over time... which might lead to a change in Y?  But real interest is the association between seasonal variation in X and health outcome Y.

Comment: 1. Do you have samples from multiple years of each subject? 2. Is Y expected to covary with X?

Comment: See the answers to this related question for some help: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88158/anova-terminology-repeated-measures-vs-within-between-subjects/88346#88346